# Inconsistent "'float' object is not iterable" error in sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

I know that there are a lot of questions with the same problem but none of them solves my problem. I am using a Jupyter Notebook in Amazon Sagemaker and I want to use the hashing trick for some features. I have not been able to make a reproducible example with simple data, but here is a screen of the data I have:
[image]

So I have used:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import FeatureHasher
h = FeatureHasher(n_features=10,input_type="string")
df['country_iso_code'] = h.transform(df['country_iso_code'])
h = FeatureHasher(n_features=10,input_type="string")
df['origen_tarjeta_country_iso'] = h.transform(df['origen_tarjeta_country_iso'])
```

The first transformation works, but the second one does not and I get the 'float' object is not iterable error. I have checked the types of both columns and they are objects and also I have checked that there are only strings in both columns. I have tried to reproduce the code in Spyder with a very little sample and it works:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction import FeatureHasher

df = pd.DataFrame({'ES':'ES','UK':'UK'},index=[0,1])
h = FeatureHasher(n_features=10,input_type="string")
df['UK'] = h.transform(df['UK'])
h = FeatureHasher(n_features=10,input_type="string")
df['ES'] = h.transform(df['ES'])
```

Comment: Object does not necessarily mean string. Maybe there is a value in that column which is of type float. Try changing the dtype of that column by using `astypr(str)`

Comment: It worked, thanks. Put as a question so that I can mark it as correct if you want, please